# Can't find maven dependencies automatically in eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, maven

i try to add some maven dependencies like "hibernate-core" with "add" feature in pom editor. But eclipse won't find dependencies automatically. Added some screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the Maven preferences and activate "download repository index ...".
2. Restart eclipse.
3. Wait until all indices are downloaded.